# Grouping week of the month that is input to linechart

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq

I have a problem when grouping weeks from input months,
the results I get are always like this

```
{name: "Pembunuhan", data: [1,4]}
```

it should be the result I want like this

```
{name: "Pembunuhan", data: [1,0,0,4]}
```

this is my code

```
 var dateNya = DateTime.Today;
 var bln = int.Parse(month);
 var mstrKategori = context.master_kategori.OrderBy("id ASC").ToList();
 var joinnya = (from ls in context.list_dokumen join ktgr in context.master_kategori on ls.kategori equals ktgr.id
                           where ls.polda_id != null
                           select new
                           {
                               tgl_laporan = ls.tgl_laporan,
                               idKategori = ktgr.id,
                               week = ls.week,
                               month = ls.month,
                               year = ls.year
                           }).ToArray();

foreach (var itemktgr in mstrKategori)
{
 var tes2 = joinnya.Where(i => i.idKategori == itemktgr.id).Where(a => a.month == bln).Where(o => o.year == dateNya.Year)
                   .GroupBy(row => new { week = row.week ?? 0 })
                   .Select(g => new
                   {
                       week = g.Key.week,
                       couny = g == null ? 0: g.Count()
                   })
                   .ToList();
tes2.ToList().ForEach(p => lineChartList.Add(new DataChart {name = itemktgr.nama2, data = p.couny}));
}
 var result = lineChartList.GroupBy(x => new { x.name })
                .Select(b => new DataChartTrending2
                {
                    data = b.Select(bn => bn.data).ToList(),
                    name = (b.Key.name == null) ? "Lainnya" : b.Key.name
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `GroupBy` clause won't create empty groups for weeks that have no matching records.

Use `GroupJoin` to perform an **outer join** on week indices, meaning that you will get a group for each week index, even indices that no record in `tes2` matched:

```
var weekIds = Enumerable.Range(0, 4); // assuming your weeks are 0, 1, 2, 3

var tes2 = joinnya
    .Where(i => i.idKategori == itemktgr.id)
    .Where(a => a.month == bln)
    .Where(o => o.year == dateNya.Year)

var countPerWeek = weekIds.GroupJoin(
    tes2,
    weekId => weekId,
    row => row.week,
    (week, weekGroup) => weekGroup.Count()
);
```

For each week, it will get you the number of matching records, including zeroes for weeks that don't have a matching record.

Alternative syntax:

```
var countPerWeek =
        from weekId in weekIds
        join row in tes2 on weekId equals row.week into weekGroup
        select weekGroup.Count();
```